# Webpage automation using Node.js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, node.js

I have an API in php which receives a 10 digit number as variable and returns some data in JSON format. Example URL : www.exampletest.com/index.php?number=8000000000 . The next variable is current number plus one. Ie, 8000000001 and so on.The sequence ends at 9999999999. And when each call is made, the output data returns in JSON format and it is written into MYSQL database. Everything seems to good up to this.

Now my problem is for each "number", I have to make a call,ie, for 8000000000,8000000001...9999999999. My friend suggested me that using node is the right option. So can someone show me an example to automate calling my php API page using node.JS for each "Number" Variable?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I recommend the "request" library for nodejs.

[the readme](https://github.com/mikeal/request/blob/master/README.md) has a few examples for easy setup.

Comment: This is something what am looking for. But the problem is am completely new to Node.js. Can you help me to modify the "request" library that  I could use in my case?

Comment: for (var i = 8000000000; i < 9999999999; i++) { // make a request with i }

Comment: you may need to use a timer to avoid firing too many requests at the same time